# Running ARM docker container with JRE on MACOS

Tags: java, macos, docker, arm

I run into the following problem, trying to run ARM docker container on MAC host.

Here is the resource I was referring to

[Cross Building and Running Multi-Arch Docker Images](https://www.ecliptik.com/Cross-Building-and-Running-Multi-Arch-Docker-Images/)

According to the blog above, Docker for Mac has binfmt_misc support built-in, which allows it to execute arm containers on x86 without any additional configuration.

What I need is to test a java app on ARM arch.

To achieve this goal I'm using the following image
[arm64v7/openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/openjdk/)

The problem is when I try to run a java app I'm constantly getting the following error

```html
   
Digest: sha256:657b2419b8407ee009e4400034e1821426d16305eb6334873b5938030f1d5f85
Status: Downloaded newer image for arm32v7/tomcat:latest
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xf4de0b90, pid=1, tid=0xe13ff470
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-1~deb9u1-b11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-aarch32 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x12eb90]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/tomcat/hs_err_pid1.log
Compiled method (c1)    3946  116             java.lang.StringBuilder::toString (17 bytes)
 total in heap  [0xf290f308,0xf290f598] = 656
 relocation     [0xf290f3d4,0xf290f3f4] = 32
 main code      [0xf290f400,0xf290f4e0] = 224
 stub code      [0xf290f4e0,0xf290f530] = 80
 metadata       [0xf290f530,0xf290f53c] = 12
 scopes data    [0xf290f53c,0xf290f554] = 24
 scopes pcs     [0xf290f554,0xf290f594] = 64
 dependencies   [0xf290f594,0xf290f598] = 4
Compiled method (c1)    3951  116             java.lang.StringBuilder::toString (17 bytes)
 total in heap  [0xf290f308,0xf290f598] = 656
 relocation     [0xf290f3d4,0xf290f3f4] = 32
 main code      [0xf290f400,0xf290f4e0] = 224
 stub code      [0xf290f4e0,0xf290f530] = 80
 metadata       [0xf290f530,0xf290f53c] = 12
 scopes data    [0xf290f53c,0xf290f554] = 24
 scopes pcs     [0xf290f554,0xf290f594] = 64
 dependencies   [0xf290f594,0xf290f598] = 4
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
```

any thoughts will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've got this too- I don't suppose you ever figured it out?

(for reference, I'm trying to ```apt-get install default-jdk-headless``` in ```arm32v7/ubuntu:16.04```

Comment: Yes, it was a while ago, I gave up trying to run it on MAC, seems like it's hasn't mature yet, just moved to the ARM on cloud as a temp solution and then bought Jetson kit

Comment: Ah, that's what I was trying to avoid (ARM in the cloud). Thanks anyway, appreciate the reply